# Not getting a 304 response even after adding ETag header

Tags: python, rest, http, http-headers, python-requests

I am trying to periodically request a server to fetch data. Since, the data doesn't change very frequently I decided to add `If-None-Match` header to optimize performance. The problem is even though the `ETag` remains the same I still get `200` status code instead of `304`. Here is a small script I wrote to verify it:

**EDIT**:

```
import requests

headers = {'Accept':'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':'Bearer XXXX'}
url = "https://api.producthunt.com/v1/posts/12330"
req = None 
response_data = None

for i in range(1,10):

    if req:
        headers = {'Accept':'application/json', 'Authorization':'Bearer XXXX', 'If-None-Match': req.headers['ETag']}
        print req.request.headers.get('If-None-Match', 'Not set') # set

    req = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

    if response_data:
        print sorted(req.json().items()) == sorted(response_data.items()) # always True

    response_data = req.json()

    print req.history # []
    print req.status_code # always 200
```

1. The `ETag` header is getting set.
2. The response data that is returned is always the same.
3. There are no redirects as `req.history` always returns an empty list.
4. I've removed the `Content-Type` header but the response is still `200`.
5. The version of requests I am using is `2.5.0`.

Comment: Same problem with me here... Have you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

- I am 7 years late on this answer, but I had a similar problem recently and fixed it by doing something like this:
- Assume you make a request to `https://api.github.com/repos/gnuradio/gnuradio`, and then you get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Sun, 20 Jun 2021 11:49:40 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
ETag: W/"113b7fb72c9708d155f1482480a4eb374ebeeedfb81abb01e4d087fd4b896910"
Last-Modified: Sun, 20 Jun 2021 10:32:21 GMT
X-GitHub-Media-Type: unknown, github.v3
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1623295573
X-RateLimit-Resource: core
X-RateLimit-Used: 1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 6534
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 059B:55A2:13A83A:298733:60D0C1F8
connection: close
```

- From there, I had to set the `If-None-Match` request header to be the value of the `ETag` header received in the previous response.
- I also set the `If-Modified-Since` request header to be the value of the `Last-Modified` header received in the previous response.

  - Not 100% sure if this header is always needed, it is not mentioned in the documentation from what I saw, but when it wasn't set it didn't seem to work in python, but it would work without setting if using the curl command.
- In python setting these two request headers is as follows:

```
headers = {}
h1 = {'If-None-Match': 'W/"113b7fb72c9708d155f1482480a4eb374ebeeedfb81abb01e4d087fd4b896910"'}
h2 = {'If-Modified-Since': 'Sun, 20 Jun 2021 10:32:21 GMT'}
headers.update(h1)
headers.update(h2)
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/gnuradio/gnuradio', headers=headers)

print(response.status_code, response.reason)
```

- This would print `304  'Not Modified'`
- Note: The `W/` before the ETag value in the request header indicates that a "weak validator" is used. I am not sure if this is always needed, but GitHub seems to implement it so using it won't hurt.

  - More info on weak validators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag

Comment: very well explained. etags takes precedence if both are present.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of things that could be happening:

1. You may not actually be adding the `ETag` header. You should check that you are using `req.request.headers.get('If-None-Match', 'Not set')` after a request. After the first request, it should never return `'Not set'`
2. The representation returned by the service may be changing. I recently helped someone debug something similar with the GitHub API (they were including a short representation of a different resource which had an attribute that could change and invalidate the ETag). You should check that the data returned to you each time is exactly the same.
3. Check `req.history` to ensure there are no redirects that are possibly causing problems
4. On a `GET` request with no request body, you shouldn't specify a `Content-Type`. There is no content so there shouldn't be a content type. (Technically the server shouldn't be bothered by it, but servers are fickle things and no one knows how they'll respond.)

Beyond all of this, could you provide the version of requests you're using?

Comment: Is the ETag returned always exactly the same or does it change from request to request?

Comment: It's exactly the same.

Comment: It does change if requests are made several hours apart.